# Grails DBMigrations plugin confusion in usage

Tags: grails, database-migration

I'm looking to introduce the Grails DBMigrations plugin into an existing application.

My understanding is that after installation the first thing to do is to create the initial changelog.groovy which I've done with the command

dbm-generate-gorm-changelog changelog.groovy

This does create the file correctly, and contains all the necessary commands to recreate the database schema.

Secondly my understanding is I should then issue the command dbm-changelog-sync to indicate that the changelog script has been executed.

What should happen if I then issue the command  dbm-gorm-diff ?

At this point I'm expecting to see an empty changelist...  because the initial schema was created, committed and no changes have been made to any domains,  however I see a bunch of entries.. for modifying column types and a few index creation entries.

Any advice appreciated,  I've reached this point because I want to update the database in a production env database, and don't want to start writing manual tests and SQL in bootstrap to update the DB as this will surely lead ultimately to a maintenance migraine. Using DBMigrations appears to be the way forward but either I don't understand it, or it's buggy and don't want to risk using it.

And as others have commented in other threads, I'm restarting the grails console between issuing commands to avoid reloading problems.

Thanks

Comment: Note: the database being used is H2, perhaps this has some quirks?

Answer (score 0):

Dave,

The important thing to remember about the migrations plugin is that is output from `dbm-gorm-diff` is not meant to be taken as gospel. It is simply meant as a way to hopefully save you from some typing. Anything generated automatically from the plugin should be reviewed and analyzed to determine that it is what you desire.